# ASP.Net OpenAuth login Method not found System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.EntityTypeConfiguration

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, owin, dotnetopenauth

I'm trying to enable login using external provider, in particular Facebook in a **webform** application.

I'm using asp.net 4.5 C# and Entity Framework 6

Local account login are working perfectly, but when I try to login using a facebook account I get the two following errors:

1- on the first time I run try to login:

**Method not found: 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter.get_ObjectContext()'.**
[StackTrace]

```
[MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter.get_ObjectContext()'.]
   Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth.EFOpenAuthMembershipDatabase.EnsureDatabaseCreated(DbContext db) +0
   Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth.EFOpenAuthMembershipDatabase.GetContext() +106
   Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth.EFOpenAuthMembershipDatabase.GetMembershipUserName(String providerName, String providerUserId, Boolean updateLastUsed) +207
   Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth.OpenAuthManager.Login(HttpContextBase context, String providerName, String providerUserId, Boolean createPersistentCookie) +285
   Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth.OpenAuth.Login(String providerName, String providerUserId, Boolean createPersistentCookie) +109
```

then
2 - everytime I try to run the login with facebook again:

**Method not found: 'Void System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.EntityTypeConfiguration'1.ToTable(System.String)'**
[StackTrace]

```
[MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.EntityTypeConfiguration'1.ToTable(System.String)'.]
   Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth.Data.OpenAuthDbContext.OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) +0
   System.Data.Entity.DbContext.CallOnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) +39
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModelBuilder() +674
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext) +61
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy'2.GetValue(TInput input) +171
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +566
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize() +31
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +39
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet'1.Initialize() +137
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet'1.get_InternalContext() +38
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery'1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() +99
   System.Linq.Queryable.Where(IQueryable'1 source, Expression'1 predicate) +83
   Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth.EFOpenAuthMembershipDatabase.GetMembershipUserName(String providerName, String providerUserId, Boolean updateLastUsed) +1486
   Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth.OpenAuthManager.Login(HttpContextBase context, String providerName, String providerUserId, Boolean createPersistentCookie) +285
   Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth.OpenAuth.Login(String providerName, String providerUserId, Boolean createPersistentCookie) +109
...]
```

Both errors are risen on the the following line (OpenAuth.Login() method) in the RegisterExternalLogin.aspx.cs:

```
if(OpenAuth.Login(authResult.Provider, authResult.ProviderUserId, createPersistentCookie: false))
        {
            RedirectToReturnUrl();
        }
```

The authResult object has correct values, so the facebook authentication works fine.
There's something wrong in the OpenAuth.Login method, when it tries to write to DB but I can't understand what, as I don't receive any clear details in debugging the error. Even with step-in debug I get the error page for that method and nothing else.

I've installed the following packages:

```
<package id="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" version="4.1.4.12333" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" version="4.1.4.12333" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Consumer" version="4.1.4.12333" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Core" version="4.1.4.12333" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Core" version="4.1.4.12333" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty" version="4.1.4.12333" targetFramework="net45" />
```

and the following for OWIN:

```
<package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
```

As in the stack trace of the first error is mentioned the OnModelCreating method, here it is:

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); // This needs to go before the other rules!

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRoles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogins");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaims").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserClaimId");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Roles").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("RoleId");
        modelBuilder.Ignore<IdentityUser>();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the package

```
Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth
```

that was version 1.0.1
Upgrading to version 2 it solve the problem of login using external account providers.
Probably there is a bug in version 1 that causes conflict with Entity Framework 6 as reported here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/811035/microsoft-aspnet-membership-openauth-is-not-compatible-with-entity-framework

Doing this causes an infinite other problem in the project as I was using **Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.*** and Identity and Membership are incompatible.

So I've removed everything related to Microsoft.AspNet.Identity, changed the DB schema for user, role, membership, etc. tables.
And now everything works fine.